# Testing flash-game on iOS without itunes/jailbreak/AppleDev?

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, ipad, flash

I recently upgraded to Flash Builder 4.7 because it bragged about it's new feature:
"Publishing ad-hoc profile apps directly to an iOS device (without using Apple iTunes or Apple XCode) is now supported on both Windows® and Mac OS."

Since I'm working on a flash game for PC it would be interesting to quickly try it on my dads iPad (or iPhone), now that I don't require iTunes apparently, which I assume means I don't need apples expensive developer subscription either.

But other than that "What's new"-tag I can't find a single piece of information if this is actually possible, not on the internet, not in the help file. All help files talks about entering your Apple subscription ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need an Apple developer license to do this. You must have a developer certificate and mobile provisioning profile, generated and signed by Apple, in order to install. Unless I am mistaken, you aren't even able to build in Flash Builder without a valid license and mobile provisioning profile (though there may be ways around that. You definitely will not be able to install it on device though, with or without iTunes/Xcode)

Flash Builder 4.7 just foregoes the messy process of adding the IPA to iTunes or Xcode and installing it manually on your device.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug via USB with Flash Builder as long as you have the device's UDID included in your development provisioning profile

> Before you debug an application on an iOS device, ensure that you have a provisioning file from Apple and an Apple-issued developer certificate that you need to convert into P12 format. For more information, follow the steps described in Prepare to build, debug, or deploy an iOS application.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-6caff02f136a645e895-7fff.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-708ff844136ba66f601-7ff6